# How to generate ELF file for QNX IFS image

Tags: arm, elf, qnx, trace32, qnx-ifs

I need to do some Trace32 debugging and i need to see the symbols of the IFS image. 
I generate the IFS image for my ARM A9 platform but dont know how to generate the ELF file. 
can somebody help me out ? 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IFS is a file system with many binaries and scripts. For trace32, when you try to debug any process (including procnto), you'd need the symbols of that process of interest. There is not such thing as ELF for IFS. It's like asking for the ELF of your harddisk.

Answer (score 0):

Use dumpifs. Example:

```
dumpifs shell.ifs
```

check [this](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/utilities/d/dumpifs.html)
the -x option can extract the files specified after the image.